# How should I write an __init__ file so that my module will appear in auto-completion of Pydev?

Tags: python, initialization, pydev

Assuming I have a package with the following structure, how should I write my init files so that every file and subpackage can be viewed in the code completion of Pydev? I know that if I added `import subpackage` in the #1 init file, I can view the subpackage in auto-completion but I doubt if this is the correct way to do it. If so, when should I consider to put an import statement in an init file?

```
package/
    __init__.py #1
    file.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
    subpackage/
        __init__.py #2
        submodule1.py
        submodule2.py
```